# tensorflow-gpu installation fails on ubuntu 18 "InvalidArchiveError('Error with archive /anaconda/pkgs/cudatoolkit-10.1.243-h6bb024c_0.tar.bz2."

Tags: python, tensorflow, anaconda, conda, ubuntu-18.04

I am trying to install tensorflow GPU on a GPU enabled ubuntu 18 machine. I installed the Nvidia drivers and using the anaconda environment for python and tensorflow. When I try to install tansorflow-gpu,

```
conda install -c anaconda tensorflow-gpu
```

the installation fails with the following error

```
InvalidArchiveError('Error with archive /anaconda/pkgs/cudatoolkit-10.1.243-h6bb024c_0.tar.bz2.  You probably need to delete and re-download or re-create this file.  Message from libarchive was:\n\nCou
ld not unlink')
```

The larger stack trace is below

```
WARNING conda.gateways.disk.delete:unlink_or_rename_to_trash(139): Could not remove or rename /anaconda/pkgs/cudatoolkit-10.1.243-h6bb024c_0/info/recipe/build.py.  Please remove this file manually (you
 may need to reboot to free file handles)
WARNING conda.gateways.disk.delete:unlink_or_rename_to_trash(139): Could not remove or rename /anaconda/pkgs/cudatoolkit-10.1.243-h6bb024c_0/info/recipe/.gitignore.  Please remove this file manually (y
ou may need to reboot to free file handles)
WARNING conda.gateways.disk.delete:unlink_or_rename_to_trash(139): Could not remove or rename /anaconda/pkgs/cudatoolkit-10.1.243-h6bb024c_0/info/recipe/LICENSE.  Please remove this file manually (you 
may need to reboot to free file handles)
WARNING conda.gateways.disk.delete:unlink_or_rename_to_trash(139): Could not remove or rename /anaconda/pkgs/cudatoolkit-10.1.243-h6bb024c_0/info/recipe/meta.yaml.template.  Please remove this file man
ually (you may need to reboot to free file handles)
WARNING conda.gateways.disk.delete:unlink_or_rename_to_trash(139): Could not remove or rename /anaconda/pkgs/cudatoolkit-10.1.243-h6bb024c_0/info/recipe/run_test.py.  Please remove this file manually (
you may need to reboot to free file handles)
WARNING conda.gateways.disk.delete:unlink_or_rename_to_trash(139): Could not remove or rename /anaconda/pkgs/cudatoolkit-10.1.243-h6bb024c_0/info/git.  Please remove this file manually (you may need to
 reboot to free file handles)
WARNING conda.gateways.disk.delete:unlink_or_rename_to_trash(139): Could not remove or rename /anaconda/pkgs/cudatoolkit-10.1.243-h6bb024c_0/info/hash_input.json.  Please remove this file manually (you
 may need to reboot to free file handles)
WARNING conda.gateways.disk.delete:unlink_or_rename_to_trash(139): Could not remove or rename /anaconda/pkgs/cudatoolkit-10.1.243-h6bb024c_0/info/index.json.  Please remove this file manually (you may 
need to reboot to free file handles)
WARNING conda.gateways.disk.delete:unlink_or_rename_to_trash(139): Could not remove or rename /anaconda/pkgs/cudatoolkit-10.1.243-h6bb024c_0/info/about.json.  Please remove this file manually (you may 
need to reboot to free file handles)
WARNING conda.gateways.disk.delete:unlink_or_rename_to_trash(139): Could not remove or rename /anaconda/pkgs/cudatoolkit-10.1.243-h6bb024c_0/info/paths.json.  Please remove this file manually (you may 
need to reboot to free file handles)
WARNING conda.gateways.disk.delete:unlink_or_rename_to_trash(139): Could not remove or rename /anaconda/pkgs/cudatoolkit-10.1.243-h6bb024c_0/info/files.  Please remove this file manually (you may need 
to reboot to free file handles)
WARNING conda.gateways.disk.delete:unlink_or_rename_to_trash(139): Could not remove or rename /anaconda/pkgs/cudatoolkit-10.1.243-h6bb024c_0/info/repodata_record.json.  Please remove this file manually
 (you may need to reboot to free file handles)
cudatoolkit-10.1.243 | 513.2 MB  | ############################################################################################################################################################## | 100% 

InvalidArchiveError('Error with archive /anaconda/pkgs/cudatoolkit-10.1.243-h6bb024c_0.tar.bz2.  You probably need to delete and re-download or re-create this file.  Message from libarchive was:\n\nCou
ld not unlink')

(base) azure@sibi-ds-gpu-vm:~$ cudatoolkit-10.1.243 | 513.2 MB  | #######################################################################################################################################
####################### | 100%
```

Any idea what this means and how to fix this ?

Comment: Have you tried following the suggested workaround in the warnings? i.e., manually deleting the files from the package cache (`/anaconda/pkgs/cudatoolkit-10.1.243-h6bb024c_0*`)?

Answer (score 0):

Install Tensorflow-GPU Using Anaconda

```
$ conda create -n tf_gpu python=3.6     # create new env, with name "tf"
$ pip install -U pip             # ensure new version available
$ conda activate tf_gpu 
$ pip install -U tensorflow
$ conda install -c anaconda cudatoolkit=10.1.243 cudnn=7.6.5   # install compatible CUDAtoolkit for your driver
$ pip install ipython
```